# How can I get the metadata of dependencies in gradle?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, groovy

I want to get all information I can get from the Gradle about each dependency I added,

I can get the dependency tree by run

```
grade dependencies
```

we get something like this

```
+--- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2
|    +--- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.20
|    +--- io.swagger:swagger-models:1.5.20
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.5 -> 2.9.0
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22 -> 1.7.26
|    |    \--- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.20
|    +--- io.springfox:springfox-spi:2.9.2 (*)
|    +--- io.springfox:springfox-schema:2.9.2
|    |    +--- io.springfox:springfox-core:2.9.2 (*)
|    |    \--- io.springfox:springfox-spi:2.9.2 (*)
|    +--- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:2.9.2
|    |    +--- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.20
|    |    +--- io.swagger:swagger-models:1.5.20 (*)
|    |    +--- io.springfox:springfox-spi:2.9.2 (*)
|    |    +--- io.springfox:springfox-schema:2.9.2 (*)
|    |    +--- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:2.9.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.4.0
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.26
|    |    +--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:2.9.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.4.0
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.26
|    +--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.2.0.Final
```

But can't get all other information about the dependencies
on how can I achieve this?

Update 
I want to get information about the creator, date, homepage of the library, library language, license type or any information that can be provided.

Comment: Which information do you need?

Comment: I update the question 
I want to get information about the creator, date, homepage of the library, library language, license type or any information that can be provided

Answer (score 0):

Gradle does not offer APIs for doing this.

If your dependencies use Maven POM file or Ivy XML as their metadata, you can access these files through an `ArtifactQuery`. There is [an example in the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.3/userguide/working_with_dependencies.html#accessing_a_modules_metadata_file) to do that.

You will however have to decide which information to extract and how to present it.